# How to play remote audio after a firebase push notification with flutter on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, audio, background-process

I need to play a remote audio directly from a firebase push notification, but I am facing some issues in case of background app.

I'am using flutter_sound for playing audios in Opus/OGG format and I followed this suggestion for reproduce audio while in background:

[Keep music app alive in background, iOS and Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646498/keep-music-app-alive-in-background-ios-and-android)

But after 30 seconds the background process is killed and the new notifications stops playing new messages.

Is there some way to renew the background process from push notifications?

Thanks, Davide.